# Remove authentication and permission classes only on one action

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a generic view set custom action and i want to remove only from this action the authentication and permission classes. I tried the following but it does not work.

```
class ExampleView(GenericViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def custom_action(self, request, format=None):
        self.authentication_classes = []
        self.permission_classes  = []
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you mark the custom action for routing with the [action decorator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing), you should be able to specify the permission classes and authentication classes.

For example:

```py
class ExampleView(GenericViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=[AllowAny], authentication_classes=[])
    def custom_action(self, request, format=None):
        ...
```